# Unexpected output while trying to print figlet

Tags: python-3.x

Friends,

I am trying to print a figlet. this is my code:

```
st1="""  
  __  __   _               _         _____                       _               
 |  \/  | (_)             | |       |  __ \                     | |              
 | \  / |  _   _ __     __| |       | |__) |   ___    __ _    __| |   ___   _ __ 
 | |\/| | | | | '_ \   / _` |       |  _  /   / _ \  / _` |  / _` |  / _ \ | '__|
 | |  | | | | | | | | | (_| |       | | \ \  |  __/ | (_| | | (_| | |  __/ | |   
 |_|  |_| |_| |_| |_|  \__,_|       |_|  \_\  \___|  \__,_|  \__,_|  \___| |_|  
 """
print(st1)
```

But instead of printing it, it is printing the below text which is difficult to read. Plz suggest. I am on windows 8 and using python 3.3.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The figlet is too long in each line of text, so the end spaces are wrapping to the next line, causing your problem.  I removed one space from the space between Mind and Reader, and also the padding to the left of Mind and it prints perfectly: [image: Mind Reader in Python Console]